# Does infinite tableau branch mean satisfiable formula?

Tags: first-order-logic

I have been taught that a formula in a First-Order Tableau is **satisfiable** if:

- it terminates with **at least an open branch**
- it has a branch that **never terminates**

Now, in case I draw a tableau for a formula and this formula doesn't terminate, given that Tableau for First-Order Logic can be proven sound and complete, can I therefore say that:

since the formula I just expands will never terminate **therefore** it must be satisfiable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, yes.

This is because "it has a non-terminating branch" is one of the defining clauses of satisfiability.